# Writing Data from pandas dataframe to PostgreSQL gives error of 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

i am trying to save a data frame which was first imported in pandas from postgresql as dfraw and then do some manipulation and create another dataframe as df and save it back in postgresql same database using sql alchemy. but when i am trying to save it back its giving error of 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

PFB code below

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


# connect the database to python
# Update connection string information 
host = "something.something.azure.com"
dbname = "abcd"
user = "abcd"
password = "abcd"
sslmode = "require"
schema = 'xyz'

# Construct connection string
conn_string = "host={0} user={1} dbname={2} password={3} sslmode={4}".format(host, user, dbname, password, sslmode)
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string) 
print("Connection established")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Fetch all rows from table
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM xyz.abc;")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

# Convert the tuples in dataframes
dfraw = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns =["ID","Timestamp","K","S","H 18","H 19","H 20","H 21","H 22","H 23","H 24","H 2zzz","H zzz4","H zzzzzz","H zzz6","H zzz7","H zzz8","H zzz9","H 60","H zzz0","H zzz2"])
dfraw[["S","H 18","H 19","H 20","H 21","H 22","H 23","H 24","H 2zzz","H zzz4","H zzzzzz","H zzz6","H zzz7","H zzz8","H zzz9","H 60","H zzz0","H zzz2"]] = dfraw[["S","H 18","H 19","H 20","H 21","H 22","H 23","H 24","H 2zzz","H zzz4","H zzzzzz","H zzz6","H zzz7","H zzz8","H zzz9","H 60","H zzz0","H zzz2"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
dfraw[["Timestamp","K"]]=dfraw[["Timestamp","K"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# Creating temp files

temp1 = dfraw
dfraw = temp1

# creating some fucntions for data manipulation and imputations

def remZero(df,dropCol):
    for k in df.drop(dropCol,axis=1):
        if all(df[k] == 0):
            continue
        if any(df[k] == 0):   
            print(k)
            df[k] = df[k].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')          
    return df

# Drop Columns function
    
dropCol = ['Timestamp','K','ID','H','C','S']
dropCol2 = ['Timestamp','K','ID','Shift']



df = remZero(dfraw,dropCol)



from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://abcd:abcd@something.something.azure.com:5432/abcd')
df.to_sql(name = df,
          con=engine,
          index = False,
          if_exists= 'replace'
          )
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VzSx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found basic error in the code I just missed putting the inverted comma before the data frame name to be published. The basic hygiene was missed

```
df.to_sql(name = "df",
      con=engine,
      index = False,
      if_exists= 'replace'
      )
```